# How to initialize array of structure in C?

Tags: c

The scenario is that I have nested structure definition, and I have an array of 10 such structure. What I want is to initialize each of the element of both parent and the child structure with zero. Code is given below:

```
struct PressureValues
{

   float SetPressure;
   float ReadPressure;

};

struct CalibrationPoints
{

   float SetTemperature;
   struct PressureValues PressurePoints[10];

};

extern volatile struct  CalibrationPoints code IntakeCalibrationPoints[10];

extern volatile struct  CalibrationPoints code DischargeCalibrationPoints[10];
```

I know the lengthy method of initializing each structure element with zero using loop, but I am looking for a short method of initializing all elements to zero. Or what is the default initialize value of array of structure (containing floats only), is it zero or any random value?

Comment: I think there's an underlying confusion here about what 'initializing' is. Short explanation below! If you already knew, then have my apologies.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
volatile struct CalibrationPoints IntakeCalibrationPoints[10] = { { 0 } };
volatile struct CalibrationPoints DischargeCalibrationPoints[10] = { { 0 } };
```

This will initialise all elements to zero.

The reason that this works is that when you explicitly initialise at least one element of a data structure then all remaining elements which do not have initialisers specified will be initialised to zero by default.

Comment: +1, the `{ 0 }` trick is IMHO the best and most fool-proof way.

Comment: Its actually not initializing all array elements of structure to zero. Infact it initializes only the first element of first structure in the array to zero. So it doesn't work.

Comment: One more thing when i tried <code> volatile struct CalibrationPoints IntakeCalibrationPoints[10] = { { 0 } };  </code> all the values are not get initialize with 1. I mean if i try any value other than zero then whether you solution will still work?

Comment: @Asad: this trick only works for zero - the default value for elements which are not explicitly initialised is zero.

Comment: @ Paul, appreciate your replies. But please let me know that if i donot intialize these arrays of structure with any default value,then will the variables have zero values as default value. Because some one told me that C default uninitilzed values are random values unless explicitly initialized

Comment: @Asad: in C you should **never** assume that variables are initialised by default - always initialise explicitly, either as part of the declaration, or with code, e.g. `memset`, a `for` loop, or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

First, I think you have a wrong notion of what 'intialize' means.

You see, when the system gives your program memory, it doesn't bother to clean up after the last program that used it. So, you can get zeroes, you can get seemingly random values, etc.

Now, your structures can't benefit from their data being randomly set, can they? So you initialize them: you give their members meaningful values, that make sense for your data. That can be all zeroes, or not. **Initializing is setting a meaningful default**, so to speak.

As for your question, you can use `memset()` to quickly zero-fill memory. Cheers! Hope I helped.

`memset()`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memset/

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
memset(IntakeCalibrationPoints, 0x00, sizeof( IntakeCalibrationPoints))
```

for example

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```
struct CalibrationPoints struct;
memset ( struct, 0, sizeof(CalibrationPoints));
`
```